# How to run a script in alcatel switches?

Tags: windows, perl, shell, putty

Can you help me to know how to run a script in a remote Alcatel Switches via putty (ssh session) please?

To run commands list, I do this:

```
C:\Desktop>putty.exe -ssh Username@host -pw password -m command.txt
```

but I have no idea how to do it for a script.

Comment: Take a look at [Object::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Remote). It lets you run a local Perl program on a target machine and all it needs there is some kind of Perl. Also watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hIyawUrCcQ) the author gave at a Perl workshop about it.

Comment: @ simbabque thank you

Answer (score 0):

Best way to run anyscript is to use "logmeTT" program for windows. 
If you are a linux user try to create your own script by using "expect /send" 
How ever another way to achive the same task is use secure CRT simple script or vbs scripts

Comment: Or use "autoit" open its recorder do the same tast only onces it will record everything (your clicks and commands)